# Background image for div not working

Tags: html, css

Why is my background-image not working?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container-fluid{
    background-image: url('G://etc/vvo/practice/img/bora1.jpg');
}
```

why drive G:? im practicing my coding during working hours and at home thats why the location is drive g

Comment: Is the path correct? Did you check the developer's tool if there are any errors in the console?

Comment: Shouldn't that be ***G:\etc\vvo\practice\img\bora1.jpg*** This is not a http-address, it's a path.

Comment: instead of absolute path, you can use relative path

Comment: i think url path is not correct...just check that...try using relative path to your css file

Comment: Check doveloper console, you might got an error like not allowed to load local resource.

Comment: in the path you got `G://etc/vvo/practice/img/bora1.jpg` you have to Slashes first, remove one. Or check @Esko answer, comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
.container-fluid{
    background-image: url('../img/bora1.jpg');
}
```

If the image contains in your project the ".." is set the path to your image

Answer (score 1):

Based from your comment, this might solve your problem. And just use a relative path, it is better and shorter.

```
.container-fluid{
   background-image: url('img/bora1.jpg');
}
```

Comment: i tried moving the pictures/images to **.css** location with the procedures you said still not working

Comment: Why did you move the images? Can you tell the directory for your css files, and the directory for your images

Comment: images goes here **G:\etc\vvo\practice\img** then the HTML and CSS **G:\etc\vvo\practice**

Comment: Edited my answer based from your comment.

Comment: Can you check for the developer's console for any errors?  Based from the locations of the files, the answer should work

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
.container-fluid{
       background:url(../img/boral.jpg);
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

just create an images folder into ur project and put ur image into that folder and then give the path to that folder like

```
<img src="images/bora1.jpg">
```

it will be easy for u. and if ur have created a special class to that image then simply use it into

```
<div>
```

Answer (score -3):

I think you can give

```
.container-fluid{
   background-image: url('bora1.jpg');
}
```

if your image is in same folder as your html page.

Comment: Doesn't make sense according to users question.

Comment: my html file is on **G:/etc/vvo/practice** and my image is on **'G:/etc/vvo/practice/img/bora1.jpg** i tried that it didnt work

Comment: click f12 and see browser developer tools go to console if it is showing error 404  that image is not found then click on image in console it will give the path of image . Then you can check the path it is taking for image